# How to create a circle to fit around a polygon?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry, polygon

Is there a way to take a polygon drawn on Google Map and create a circle that would perfectly encompass the polygon? We have users drawing a polygon on a map for a particular purpose, but we also need to describe the area they selected as a circle (Lat/Lon centre point and radius). It's for a really low resolution representation of their selection but it **must** be a circle. Please see the illustration I've drawn:

[Circle computed to fit around polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcJTi.jpg)

I've Googled and read for hours without luck. Someone must have done this before and written a library or code snippet. Thanks in advance if anyone can share or help please?

Comment: I don't have the time to attempt to type some code out, but there are functions here on SO for finding the center of your polygon, so I would: 1. find your poly's center, 2. create variable for your furthest point from it , 3. write function to create a circle with a radius using your variable (for it's size), then 4. place the circle on your center point of your poly.

Comment: Can you provide some sample polygons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a [Smallest Enclosing Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) for polygon vertices. `Miniball` link at wiki page provides C++ and Java code for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link, MBo, and for giving this geometric problem its name - Smallest Enclosing Circle. With that information I was able to do a better search and found that someone had already written some JavaScript to do this and a really good online demo. http://www.nayuki.io/page/smallest-enclosing-circle
As this answer led me to the code I needed I'll mark it as the answer.